# Tools for Deployment of Web Apps

Tags: .net, deployment

Just wondering if people are using any particular tools to improve the experience of deploying  web applications ( and applications in general) on the .Net stack
I use a bunch of scripts and [FluentMigrator](http://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) for my db schema support.
But I need to change my web.config, ftp stuff up and down, seems rather manual
I m sure there are better ways, please enlighten me 
I forgot to add. I m already using msbuild or nant to do some scripting.

Comment: Are you using VS? If so, what version?

Comment: I m surprised no one mentioned Rake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [web.config transformations](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621010228/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx) Visual Studio 2010 provides inbuilt support for this.

You should also check the [Web Deployment Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/introduction-to-web-deploy).

> Web Deploy (Web Deployment Tool) is an
> IIS extension, containing essentially
> a set of tools and a managed framework
> for simplifying the deployment,
> management and migration of Web
> applications, sites, and even entire
> servers.

The [Visual Web Developer Team Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20120703022755/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/) and the [Web Deployment Team Blog](https://iis-blogs.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy) are also good resources on this specific topic.

Answer (score 0):

In our shop we are using Team Foundation Build (we use TFS for source control) and MSBuild to deploy our applications.  You can write task in .NET which gives you unlimited flexibility.  [Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286) was a good starting point.  The introduction of [config transformations in Visual Studio 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/16/visual-studio-2010-web-config-transforms.aspx) will make this even more powerful.  We use this to deploy several different web applications and click-once applications across testing, acceptance, and production environments.